# Gutzwiller mean-field method in Bose Hubbard model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, cold-atoms

[Gutzwiller](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805329) mean-felid method is an efficient way to study Bose-Hubabrd model in optical lattice with a harmonic trap. Gutzwiller method assumes there is no spatial correlation within the trap, so different sites do not "talk" to one another. We can treat each site independently. But why the final ground state by Gutzwiller method is different from ground state by the local density approximation in a trap?

Comment: What do you mean by "groud-state by LDA in a trap"? Do you mean the exact ground-state or the ground-state of the Gutzwiller wf in the homogeneous case + LDA ?

Comment: In the second case, a partial answer is that the LDA is an additional approximation. Imagine using the Gutzwiller wf with the trap (solution $\psi_1$). Now solve with Gutzwiller wf in a homogeneous system, giving $\psi_2$. Using the LDA on $\psi_2$ is an additional approximation, and there is no reason to get the same results than $\psi_1$, which takes the trap into account in a more precise manner.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! By LDA I mean treat each site independently with a local potential and solve it with Gutzwiller method. I know in most cases, people use LDA as an initial guess to minimize the energy and find the ground sate.

Comment: Then this is not what people usually mean by LDA. To use the LDA correctly in this case, one must compute $\psi(\mu)$ in the homogeneous case (no trap) within the Gutzwiller approximation for all $\mu$ (which is independent of position, by symmetry), and then plot $\psi(\mu-V_i)$ with $V_i$ the value of the trap at site $i$. If you put the trap directly in the hamiltonian, this is beyond the LDA (since you find $\psi_i(\mu)$ which is different from $\psi(\mu-V_i)$).

Comment: @Adam Yes, I agree with you. Assume the total sites is M and maximum occupation number on each site is N_c.  My confusion is why the Gutzwiller wavefunciton amplitudes (calculate the N_c+1 vector f on each site, then glue f's of each site together, so it becomes a M*(N_c+1) vector)calculated by LDA is different from the wavefunciton amplitudes f's calculated by minimizing the M*(N_c+1) parameters directly.

Comment: The hand-waving argument is that the the LDA is done on top of the Gutzwiller approximation. In some sense, the Gutzwiller with the trap includes some quantum effects of the trap in it (it treats the inhomogeneities in a more consistent way).